# Bundling a subfolder's index.js with rollup and requiring modules from main directory

Tags: javascript, bundle, es6-modules, rollup

I am building a framework, in which I want to have examples folder, like this:

./framework-core

./framework-constants

./framework-helpers

./examples

I want to be able to run the examples with rollup when I download the framework from github, using commands in my package.json such as:

`"app0": "rollup examples/app0/app.js --format iife --name 'bundle' --file examples/app0/bundle.js"`

In my `app0/app.js` file I include the framework's main parts, like this:

`import { FrameworkClass } from '../../framework-core'`

Upon running my `app0` command from the cli, I get the following error `[!] Error: Could not resolve '../../akira-core' from examples/app0/app.js`

I understand this has to do with my relative paths, but am unable to get it working. Is this how it should be done? Is there a smarter way I am missing? Any help is more then welcome.